# Pythonanywhere - ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111]

Tags: django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

Here I have a model called User. It has 2 fields  "Name" and "Phone".
I am trying to authenticate with an OTP. Actually the code works fine on the local server. For this reason, I hosted the project on Pythonanywhere, but now it's getting an error on the server
**ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused**

## Essentials

Below is the code for the OTP message to send

```
def generate_otp(user, name, phone):
    otp = users.models.User.objects.make_random_password(length=4, allowed_chars='123456789')

    if not users.models.VerifyToken.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        users.models.VerifyToken.objects.create(user=user, otp=otp, name=name, phone=phone)
        send_verification_message(phone, otp)
    else:
        token = users.models.VerifyToken.objects.get(user=user)
        token.otp = otp
        token.name = name
        token.phone = phone
        send_verification_message(phone, otp)
        token.save()
    return otp

def send_verification_message(phone, otp):
    phone = phone[3:14]
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.msg91.com")
    payload = "{ \"sender\": \"BMyDay\", \"route\": \"4\", \"country\": \"91\", \"sms\": [ { \"message\": \"" + "Your verification code is " + otp + ".\", \"to\": [ \"" + phone + "\" ] } ] }"
    print(payload)
    headers = {
        'authkey': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'content-type': "application/json"
    }

    conn.request("POST", "/api/v2/sendsms", payload, headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()

    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    return True
```

## View

This is my view

```
class AuthAPIView(APIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "phone"
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    # Get OTP
    def put(self, request):
        name = request.data.get('name')
        phone = request.data.get('phone')

        if name and phone and phonenumbers.is_valid_number(
                phonenumbers.parse(request.data.get('phone'), 'IN')):
            # if user is exists
            if VerifyToken.objects.filter(phone=phone).exists():
                user = VerifyToken.objects.get(phone=phone).user
                generate_otp(user, name, phone)
            elif User.objects.filter(phone=phone).exists():
                user = User.objects.get(phone=phone)
                generate_otp(user, name, phone)
            else:
                username = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10)
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, phone=phone)
                generate_otp(user, name, phone)

            return Response({'response': 'OTP send to your mobile number: ' + str(phone), "user": user.id},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            return Response({'response': 'Enter a valid data'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## Error

This is the server error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/BookMyDay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/bookmyday_python/source/users/api_view.py", line 121, in put
    generate_otp(user, name, phone)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/bookmyday_python/source/source/essentials.py", line 42, in generate_otp
    send_verification_message(phone, otp)
  File "/home/BookMyDay/bookmyday_python/source/source/essentials.py", line 63, in send_verification_message
    conn.request("POST", "/api/v2/sendsms", payload, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1407, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 946, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

## Postman response

```
<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Error happens when you try to make a request to external API `conn.request("POST", "/api/v2/sendsms", payload, headers)`. The connection was dropped and raised an error.

Comment: @Charnel :- Then what should I do? It works fine on the local. Do I need to change any code? can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably on a free account that needs to access the internet through our proxy, but I don't see anywhere that you have configured your http library to use the proxy. Some libraries (like requests) use the proxy settings automatically and others do not. Search the PythonAnywhere help pages for "proxy" to find the proxy details and configure your http library to use them.

Comment: Yes, you are right I am using the free account. I'll check. Thanks for the info

Comment: Can you suggest any library for proxy? Or any other reference

Comment: Is the file `/home/BookMyDay/bookmyday_python/source/source/essentials.py` code that you've written yourself, which is using the Python http library to make outbound connections?  If so, I'd suggest changing it to use the `requests` library instead.  That's a much easier way to do HTTP stuff in Python, and it is proxy-aware -- that is, it reads in the proxy details from its runtime environment and uses it without you having to write any proxy code yourself.